Create an image by using layers with other images in C#
I'm working on a project that uses randomly generated characters exploring a dungeon. I wanted the images of the characters, NPCs and monsters used in the game to be generated based off of a base model.
I wanted to do this by adding several images with transparent backgrounds together onto a new image to create a new image out of the layers, and then place this image into its own folder so it could be referenced later. It would look something like this:
    //gets the directory of the project        
    String sourceDir = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetParent(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory).FullName).FullName).FullName).FullName; 
        
            String path = sourceDir + "\\res\\Characters\\male\\"; //creates the path
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(128, 128);  //base image to add layers onto
            Random rand = new Random(); //used to randomly select images from a directory


            List<Bitmap> hats = new List<Bitmap>(); //creates the hats list
            //add hats to list
            hats.Add(new Bitmap(path + "hats\\hats1.png")); //error keeps throwing here
            hats.Add(new Bitmap(path + "hats\\hats2.png"));


            //same as above
            List<Bitmap> faces = new List<Bitmap>();
            //same as above
            faces.Add(new Bitmap(path + "faces\\faces1.png"));
            faces.Add(new Bitmap(path + "faces\\faces2.png"));



            rand.Next(0, hats.Count);   //create random index


            Bitmap image = hats[Convert.ToInt32(rand)];  //create bitmap
            using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))   //adds layers to image
            {
                
                g.DrawImage(image, 0, 0);
           
            }

            
            rand.Next(0, faces.Count);
            image = faces[Convert.ToInt32(rand)];
            using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                g.DrawImage(image, 0, 0);

            }


            image.Save(path + "\\res\\Characters");

Running this program gives me issues with the parameters of the problem, it keeps giving me a parameters error in line 8 ("System.ArguementExecption: Parameter Not Valid"). I think it is an issue with accessing the png files in the path to manipulate them.
I assume someone's probably done something like this but for the life of me I can't find any guide on how to do something like this in C# after a couple days of googling. Everything is either some part of a larger project or a dead link.
I have the aforementioned pseudo-code that has roughly what I want to do but I don't know how to implement the functions in between that edit images, overlay images and save images to a specific folder.

Your concept is fine - but please don't use System.Drawing (GDI) for this - instead take a look at Direct2D.

Maybe the image was not deleted before you created it again?

Which image was not deleted? The image in "image"?
